# Select list display issue

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Good morning,
within Oracle Apex Application Builder I'm trying to create a order product page which displays products from a product table, shows a select list which a user can use to define the quantity in which they want to order. Using a classic report to display my code, the declared table columns were generated and outputted on the report,  however the select list column only shows the html syntax used to create a select list and not the actual drop down select list with values.

Here is the code:

```
select p.product_id, 
   p.product_name, 
   p.product_price, 
   apex_item.hidden(1, p.product_id) ||
      apex_item.hidden(2, p.product_price) || 
      apex_item.select_list(
          p_idx           =>   3,
          p_value         =>   nvl(c.c003,'Add_to_cart'),
          p_list_values   =>   '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10',
          p_show_null     =>   'YES',
          p_null_value    =>   0,
          p_null_text     =>   '0',
          p_item_id       =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
          p_item_label    =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
          p_show_extra    =>   'NO') "add_to_cart"
from prod p, apex_collections c
WHERE c.collection_name (+) = 'ORDER_ITEMS'
and c.c001 (+) = p.product_id
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, how to correct my issue and if there are better ways to implement a select list; as I need this code to work for my project?

Thanks in-advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Builder, navigate to that column so that you'd see its properties. Scroll down to **Escape special characters** and set it to "No". Then run the report and see whether there's any improvement (should be).

Comment: YOU ABSOLUTE GEM! Thank you very much, its surprising none of my tutors picked that up!

Comment: Just curious, the order page works fine, however on the order summary page none of the stored values are displaying what's the cause?   
              `select (select product_name from prod p where 
              product_id = 
              c.c001) as product_name,
              c.c002 as product_price,
              c.c003 as product_quantity,
              (c.c002 * c.c003) as total_cost
              from apex_collections c
              where c.collection_name = 'order_items'
              and c.c003 <> 0
              order by 1;`

Comment: I don't know; does APEX_COLLECTIONS contain data when you're on that page? I don't use it; I prefer storing data into my own tables.

Comment: APEX_COLLECTIONS helps store values temporary which i used to store my select list user values,  so that i can call on it in the order summary page to calculate the total cost. But it doesn't seem to be working hmm

Comment: So, does a simple `select * from apex_collections` display anything if you run it on your "order summary page"? No conditions, just that query.

Comment: Nothing is displayed at all when I run that select query which means i don't think any of my values from the product select page are being stored

Comment: Well, that's most probably the cause. Either investigate *why* is that happening (as I've said, I don't use APEX_COLLECTIONS and can't help much, apart from reading the documentation which I can't do right now), or switch to your own table.